# Monitor automatically immidiately disables

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have a laptop (nvidia GPU) with two external monitors connected. One of them is connected via a USB-C to DP adapter. This one works fine. The other is connected via a HDMI cable.

The HDMI-cable-connected one refuses to stay enabled. I select it and click enable but when I click "apply", the montoris flicker off and on and the monitor is automatically disabled again. See screenshots:

[image]

I click to enable it and press the "apply" button.

This is the result

[image]

Can someone help me?

Comment: Have you tried possibly another HDMI cable?  I have seen some pretty strange things with HDMI cables that physically look good.